# учитываются ли в статистике google play файлы apk

Tags: android

Я выложил программу на несколько альтернативных ресурсов в формате apk. Будут ли они учитываться в статистике google play? Или к примеру пользователь скачал apk, установил, будет ли он потом обновляться через google play и как это будет в консоли разработчика в статистике отображаться?

Comment: я не уверен на 100%, но данные об установках точно будут только для установок из Google Play. Обновляться возможно будет, но для этого APK должны быть полностью одинаковые, одинаково подписанные. Google Play вроде может подхватить такие APK

Comment: Файл АПК тот же, что и на гугл плей. Получается, что узнать на скольких устройствах на данный момент установлено приложение, если оно распространялось не только через гугл плей невозможно.

Comment: Гугл плей не узнает никак о том, что приложение, например, установили на устройство без доступа в интернет. Так же само не узнает и о том, что такое приложение удалили. Это невозможно просто физически.

Comment: А если у устройства есть интернет, и приложение было установлено через apk скачанное, к примеру, с 4pda?

Comment: Все равно вряд ли. По крайней мере, полагаться на это точно не стоит.

Answer (score 1):

В консоли разработчика Google Play для каждого приложения можно посмотреть следующую статистику:

1. Количество установок и удалений;
2. Обновления;
3. Рейтинг;
4. Сбои и ошибки ANR ("Приложение не отвечает");
5. Информацию о пользователях;
6. Запросы на регистрацию и сообщения Google Cloud Messaging (GCM).
7. Данные доступны, если сервис GCM соответствующим образом настроен и связан с приложением на странице Сервисы и API. Подробнее о GCM…

**Данные доступны, если вы связали свой аккаунт разработчика с аккаунтом Google Analytics.**

Чтобы посмотреть статистику отдельного приложения, выполните следующие действия:

1. Войти в консоль разработчика Google Play.
2. Нажать "Все приложения" All applications.
3. Выбрать нужное.
4. Нажать Статистика в меню слева.

Данные на странице Статистика указаны по тихоокеанскому времени (PT) и ежедневно обновляются.

Comment: Вы вопрос прочитали?

Comment: @metalurgus, что не так?

Comment: Вопрос о том, будет ли отображаться в Google Play консоли разработчика статистика об установках со сторонних источников (APK файлы, другие магазины приложений...)

Comment: @metalurgus, что, собственно говоря, не понятно? данные будут отображаться, если аккаунт связан `Google Analytics`.